# jqModal / jquery and IE7 - invalid property value error

Tags: jquery

I am getting a weird "invalid property value error" which only happens in IE7. This is my code:

```
 showTypes = function(id,projNum,flag) {
    formData = 'vw=blah&id='+id+'&projNum='+projNum+'&flag='+flag;

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",        
        url: "myURL.cfm",
        data: formData,        
        cache: false,       
        success: function(result) { 
            $('#jqmTitle').html('Details for : '+projNum);
            $('#jqmText').html(result);
            $('#jqmTypes').jqmShow();
        },
        error: function(xmlHttpRequest, status, err) {
            confirm('Error!' + err );
        }
    });
}
```

it breaks on $('#jqmText').html(result);
any help?

UPDATE: it looks like IE7 does not like one of the following:

```
$('#blah-9').attr('disabled', true);
$('#blah-9').css('color','grey');
```

Comment: You have a strange `*/` character at the end of line 10 and poorly encoded POST data values due to the string concatenations of `formData`.

Comment: What is `*/` in there for? :)

Comment: sorry forgot to remove. i was commenting out parts of the code to see where it was breaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wow. IE7 does not like grey, replaced it with #CCC and it worked .

Comment: mohahaa, epic fail on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding this to your ajax parameters?

```
dataType: "html"
```

Since I don't know what you are returning its hard to test.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the jqmShow() function. Modern browsers just ignore that line, but IE7 is trying like mad to run it and can't find it anywhere.

Comment: This is part of my code. I have a <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jqModal.js" ></script> at the top of my page, which defines jqmShow(). As I mentioned, the error was because of the "grey". It works after I put the color code instead. Amazing thing is this works in IE8, FF fine.